# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method...) Works locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I didn't have trouble on previous code pushed to Heroku, but this last push has messed up. The only thing that has changed is instead of looping through each `student`, it's now looping through each `user`.

## **Background**

The code works locally, but not on Heroku. The page that is raising an error on Heroku is a list (index) of all the students. What the code is doing is looping through all `Users` that have a `profile_type = "Student"`.

For some reason it's trying to access the polymorphic association (profile) on a Student object, when the User object should be used instead.

**Log from Heroku**

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `profile' for #<Student:0x007f80c5552330>):
35:         <tbody>
36:          <% @students.each do |user| %>
37:           <tr>
38:             <td><%= link_to user.profile.ivywise_id, student_path(user.profile_id) %></td>
39:             <td><%= link_to user.first_name.camelize, student_path(user.profile_id) %></td>
40:             <td><%= link_to user.last_name.camelize, student_path(user.profile_id) %></td>
41:             <td><%= user.email %></td>
app/views/students/index.html.erb:38:in `block in_app_views_students_index_html_erb__3704269538007702833_70095521176320'
app/views/students/index.html.erb:36:in `_app_views_students_index_html_erb__3704269538007702833_70095521176320'
```

## **Application Code**

**student.rb**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :profile, dependent: :destroy
...
```

**students_controller**

```
def index
  @students = User.where(profile_type: "Student").order("last_name")
end
```

**index.html.erb for students**

```
  <% @students.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to user.profile.ivywise_id, student_path(user.profile_id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to user.first_name.camelize, student_path(user.profile_id) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to user.last_name.camelize, student_path(user.profile_id) %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_student_path(user.profile_id), class: "btn btn-default btn-small" if can? :edit, Student %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, :polymorphic => true
```

**What I have tried:**

- Double checked that all migrations from local/dev are in sync with Heroku
- Cloned the Heroku files to double check that they are running the same codebase
- Ran the `heroku restart` command
- Double checked and ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` to make sure everything
- Double checked the database to make sure all data and columns are the same
- I've checked on other machines and browsers; still the same issue

Definitely frustrating... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried starting the app locally in production mode and seen if you get the same error?

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the suggestion... didn't think of testing it in production mode. At least now I'm able to recreate the issue and narrow it down.

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed anything else?  The data type is shown as `Student`, and it says there is no method `profile` for a variable of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Leo Correa's suggestion, I started the rails server in production mode and was able to reproduce the error. (I used the `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` to launch the server locally in production mode.)

I narrowed the issue down to `config.eager_load`. It was originally set to `true`, but changing it to `config.eager_load = false` fixed the issue.

Still not sure why the issue persisted in the first place, but it's fixed now!

Comment: I had the exact same problem I fixed in the same way, thank you btw. Any idea why it happened? And should I change back to `config.eager_load = true` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and setting `config.eager_load` to `true` fixed it. However this is not a recommended setting in production, so I tried to find out what was really the issue.

I finally realised that it was because of some other model class that was incorrectly set up (it was still under development), **even though it had absolutely nothing to do** with the erroring models. When the `config.eager_load` option is set to `true` it causes Rails to load all classes at startup for optimisation reasons. If some model classes are incorrect, then this causes things to be messed up and the relations may become weird.

As soon as I deleted the wrong/incomplete model class, everything started to work again.

Comment: I took another look based on your suggestion and looked through all the model classes, but everything seems to be set up fine.

What did you _bad_ model look like? As long as the Model Class inherits from ActiveRecord::Base, it should be fine.

Comment: I had another model that was incomplete and had a relation to the one that was failing. The incomplete model wasn't used anywhere in the code, but it was loaded at start up because of config.eager_load. By incomplete I mean the relation was set up incorrectly. It was working locally because the model was never loaded, but not in prod environment where it was loaded.