# Ruby Polymorphic association working locally but not in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, polymorphic-associations

Similar issue of the question below, but need a different solution

[ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method...) Works locally, but not on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804564/actionviewtemplateerror-undefined-method-works-locally-but-not-on-hero)

My polymorphic association Address>Account is working locally, but when I upload it to Heroku I get the following error when rendering the view:

```
Rendered addresses/show.html.erb within layouts/application (101.1ms)
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947013+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947015+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `addressable' for nil:NilClass):
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947016+00:00 app[web.1]:     1: <div id="central">
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947017+00:00 app[web.1]:     2:     <h1><%= @addresses.addressable.try(:name) %></h1> 
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947018+00:00 app[web.1]:     3:     <h5><%= @addresses.addressable_type %> Address </h5>
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947018+00:00 app[web.1]:     4:     <div id="limiter">
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947020+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/addresses/show.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_addresses_show_html_erb__1277570398496108107_69968312940660'
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947019+00:00 app[web.1]:     5:     <table class="tbig" align="center" style="width:100%;">
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947021+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-09T03:04:14.947021+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

The models are setup like this:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :addresses, :as => :addressable
    has_many :contacts
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :addressable, :polymorphic => true 
end
```

The database table like:

```
class CreateTableAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
    t.string :no    
    t.string :street
    t.string :suburb
    t.string :code
    t.text :details
    t.belongs_to :city
    t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true, index: true
    t.timestamps null: false    
    end
  end
end

class CreateTableAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
     create_table :accounts do |t|
     t.text :name
     t.string :no
     t.string :site
     t.string :email
     t.string :phone1
     t.string :phone2
     t.text :details
     t.timestamps null: false
     end
    end
 end
```

The Address view which is receiving the error when coming from show_accounts

```
<div id="central">
    <h1><%= @addresses.addressable.try(:name) %></h1> 
    <h5><%= @addresses.addressable_type %> Address </h5>
    <div id="limiter">
    <table class="tbig" align="center" style="width:100%;">
    <col width="50%">
    <col width="50%">
    <tr><th colspan="2" class="bottom">Address Details</th></tr>    
        <tr class="odd">
        <td class="left">Address System ID: </td>
        <td class="right output"> <%= @addresses.id %> </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        <td class="left">Number: </td>
        <td class="right output"> <%= @addresses.no %> </td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        <td class="left">Street: </td>
        <td class="right output"><%= @addresses.street %></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="even">
        <td class="left">Suburb:</td>
        <td class="right output"><%= @addresses.suburb %></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
        <td class="left">Post Code: </td>
        <td class="right output"><%= @addresses.code %></td>
    </tr>
        <tr class="even">   
        <td colspan="2" class="bottom"> <%= @addresses.details %></td>     </tr>
        <tr><th colspan="2" class="bottom"></th></tr>
    </table>
<div id="menu">
<ul class="menu">
    <!-- Access Check - Edit Address -->
    <% if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:2).try(:canupdate?) %>
    <li> <%= link_to (image_tag("address_edit.png", :width => "70%")), edit_address_path %>
    <br /><%= link_to "Edit Address", edit_address_path %></li>
    <% end %>

    <!-- back Accounts -->
    <li> <%= link_to (image_tag("address_back.png", :width => "70%")),  @addresses.addressable  %>
    <br /><%= link_to "Back", @addresses.addressable %></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
 </div>
```

and the addresses controller:

class AddressesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :logged_in_user

```
def address_params
    params.require(:address).permit(:id, :no, :street, :suburb, :code, :details, :city_id, :addressable_type, :addressable_id)
end


def new
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canwrite?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"New")
        @addresses = Address.new(:addressable_type => params[:addressable_type],:addressable_id => params[:addressable_id])
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"New !Access Denied! ")
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to create Addresses."
    redirect_to :back
    end
end

def create
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canwrite?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Create", details: address_params)
        @address = Address.new(address_params)
        if @address.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Address Saved'
        redirect_to @address.addressable
        else
        render "new"
        end
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Create !Access Denied! ")
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to create Addresses."
    redirect_to :back
    end
end


def edit
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canupdate?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Edit", details: params[:id])
        @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Edit !Access Denied! ", details: params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to edit Addresses."
    redirect_to :back
    end
end

def update
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canupdate?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Update", details: address_params)
        @accounts = Account.all
        @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
        if @addresses.update_attributes(address_params)
        redirect_to @address.addressable
            flash[:notice] = 'Account Updated'
        else 
        render "edit"
        flash[:error]
        end
    else
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to edit Addresss."
    redirect_to back
    end
end

def show
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:canread?)
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"View", details: params[:id])
        @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
    else
    @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"View !Access Denied! ", details: params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to view Addresss."
    redirect_to back
    end
end

def destroy
    if Accessrule.find_by(role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace:3).try(:candelete?)
        @addresses = Address.find(params[:id])
        @logs = Log.create(user_id: current_user.id , role_id: current_user.role_id, workspace_id:3, action:"Delete", details: params[:id])
        @addresses.destroy
        redirect_to :back
        flash[:notice] = 'Address Deleted'
    else
    flash[:notice] = "You don't have access to delete Addresss."
    redirect_to :back
        end
end


    # Before Filters
    # Confirms if User is logged-in
    def logged_in_user
     unless logged_in?
     flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
     redirect_to root_path
     end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your association has absolutely nothing to do here with the error. Always look at the entire error message, especially at `for nil:NilClass`. The problem is that your `@addresses` gives `nil`, which can happen when searching for the record that don't exist in the database:

```
@addresses = Address.find(params[:id]) # Can return nil
```

Apart from that - your variable names are quite confusing. When expecting a single object (not a collection), please use singular `address`, plural `addresses` suggests it's a relation object.

Comment: But the record exits, and is accessible by local server, which uses the production database. Even if I try to show the view by the url I get the same error.

Comment: Fact is that `Address.find` returns nil. How do you connect locally to production DB? Try opening rails console (`heroku run rails c`) and check what you'll get there. Also: you have `back` instead of `:back` at the bottom of the show method.

Comment: Wait, what? :) Naming is just naming, the only way it could be the problem is when your variables in controller and those in views differs, but they seem all right. The fact it works is actually a symptom of some bigger issue.

Comment: That's the point, since is a many to one (one Account can have many addresses), even with the variables names matching it, when trying to get addresses.addressable, it couldn't find the addressable because is associated with the singular form of @ address, where we have the polymorphic addressable_id, and addressable_type.  @ address belongs to addressable, but something in heroku was not getting @ addresses.addressable like locally. If I figure out I put it here for the community

Comment: Yeah you were right. Not sure why heroku is not working like locally, will check with their support, even that show is working now, I can't create new addresses in heroku but can locally :(